# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I am trying to add a GLSurfaceView but I am getting below error- java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.GLSurfaceView;

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{fashizel.mizi/fashizel.mizi.MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class GLSurfaceView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class GLSurfaceView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
        at fashizel.mizi.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:14)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.GLSurfaceView
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:643)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
```

**This error comes on both it real device and genymotion emulator**
I think there is something related to the fact that there is no visual representation in the layout editor.

this is the layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MyActivity">

<GLSurfaceView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`GLSurfaceView` is in the `android.opengl` package, not `android.view`.

Hence, in your XML layout file, change `GLSurfaceView` to `android.opengl.GLSurfaceView`.

Comment: Changed the imports, Didn't change a thing. thanx

Comment: @YakirYehuda: Your problem is not with an import. Your problem is with your `<GLSurfaceView>` element, which should be `<android.opengl.GLSurfaceView>`. Or, if you created a custom subclass, it should be the fully-qualified class name of your subclass.